# Facebook Android SDK Request failing randomly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to get is users friends birthdays. In order to get that I first make request for all the friends :

```
Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session,"me/friends", new   Request.Callback() { ...
```

and then inside callback I am making new request asking for user details :

```
Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session,userID, new Request.Callback() { ...
```

Problem I am facing is that sometimes it works ok but sometimes I get strange response :

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

In some thread someone suggested that this might be because of user blocking 3rd party apps getting info about them. I do not think it is true since after number of retries I finally get all the details. They seem to fail on random order.

I tried logging :

```
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
```

but I do not see anything related in log.

Any ideas what might cause it or how to log the error?

thanks
w